# Scatter plot with larger value appear on top

Tags: r, plotly

Is there a way to render the points such that the larger values are always on top of lower values?

The similar idea is implemented in R-seurat package. In the function `FeaturePlot`, it has a argument called `order`. The [description](https://rdrr.io/cran/Seurat/man/FeaturePlot.html) of this argument is as follow: "Boolean determining whether to plot cells in order of expression. Can be useful if cells expressing given feature are getting buried."

When `order = FALSE`

```
Seurat::FeaturePlot(x, "feature", cols = c("grey90", viridis::inferno(10000, begin = 0, end = 1, direction = -1)), reduction = "pca", dims = c(2,3))
```

[image: enter image d here]

When `order = TRUE`

```
Seurat::FeaturePlot(x, "feature", cols = c("grey90", viridis::inferno(10000, begin = 0, end = 1, direction = -1)), reduction = "pca", dims = c(2,3), order = TRUE)
```

[image]

The two figures are plotted with same data. But, you may notice that the purple dot become more. It is because it was underneath the yellow ones.

I would like to implement this in the scatter plot of plotly. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: More details would be helpful. What have you tried? Can you provide some data that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Have you considered searching on the topic of transparency?

Comment: Try sorting the data before plotting.

Comment: @Dave2e order works! Thanks.

Comment: Probably it is better to add the answer below in the answer section instead of editing the question. You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Suggested by @Dave2e: The order the data matters.

```
x <- tibble(x = rnorm(1000),
        y = rnorm(1000), 
        z = c(rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 10), rnorm(900, mean = 0, sd = 1)))

x$z <- sort(x$z) ## order step

plotly::plot_ly(x,
  x = ~x,
  y = ~y,
  text = ~z,
  
  type = "scatter",
  mode = "markers",
  marker = list(
    size = 10,
    color = ~z,
    colorscale = "Portland",
    colorbar = list(
      yanchor = "middle",
      y = 0.5,
      ypad = 20,
      thickness = 15
    )
  )
)
```

before order[image]

after order[image]